# Does multiple tabs of same site send multiple ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, performance, browser, tabs

Let imagine we have site what every second check is there any new messages:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'message_check.php',
            success: function(data){
               if(data)$('#someDiv').html('NEW MESSAGE!');              
            }
         });
    },1000);
});
```

Now someone opened 3 tabs with different pages of my site.

How many call I'll get every second, **three** or **one**?

- if one then **how tabs sinc**?
- if three then **we lost very very much performance**, right?

Noticed what **Firebug** show same console for different pages of same site. It means what **FireFox** in my case (and I hope other browser too) **understand what it same site** and can avoid multiple calls.

I think about saving result into cookie and make call only if it's not "fresh", but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its depends on the browser you use. Some browsers use only 2 concurrect connections to the server, hence you will get up to 2 concurrent hits from your multi-tab browser client. So if you javascript generates multiple requests, they will be quied & managed by the browser.

Comment: So browser will not check if call with that params already in action. It will check only is limit excited or not, right?

Comment: Yes. It will queue up such requests.

Comment: Hmm, then adding cookie check is not so effective. Thanks.